# Обновление Activity при изменение данных в Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Если я удаляю или добавляю что то на сервере мой Activity в котором я нахожусь и отображаю данные, перезагружается , это очень плохо в моей ситуации, как это исправить ?

так я получаю данные с сервера:

```
 reference.child(userId).child("KEYS").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            codes.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class));
            codesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Codes code = dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(code);

            codes.set(index, code);
            codesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);



        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Codes code = dataSnapshot.getValue(Codes.class);

            int index = getItemIndex(code); // строка 105 с ошибкой 

            codes.remove(index);
           // codesAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

В логах дает ошибку:

> 03-17 17:21:55.163 16169-16169/com.maikmarelostydios.a240417gid E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                            at com.maikmarelostydios.a240417gid.MainActivity.getItemIndex(MainActivity.java:142)
>                                                                                            at com.maikmarelostydios.a240417gid.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:28)
>                                                                                            at com.maikmarelostydios.a240417gid.MainActivity$1.onChildRemoved(MainActivity.java:105)
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
>   03-17 17:21:55.166 15784-15784/? E/wpa_supplicant: RSSI=-30;LINKSPEED=72;NOISE=9999;FREQUENCY=2412;

Строки с ошибками из логов:

```
private int getItemIndex(Codes codes1) {

    int index = -1;

   for (int i = 0; i < codes.size(); i++) {
        if (codes.get(i).key.equals(codes1.key)) {  //это строка 142
           index = i;
            break;
       }
   }
   return index;
```

}

```
  int index = getItemIndex(code); // это строка 105 она если в коде выше
```

Comment: Что значит `данные перезагружается`, чем это плохо и что именно вы хотите сделать иначе?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб необходимо получить изменение при этом избегая перезагрузку Activity

Comment: В приведённом коде нет перезагрузки активити. Расскажите что именно у вас происходит. В данный момент проблемы не видно никакой. Может вам надо просто анимацию изменения ячейки убрать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб данные я отображаю в RecycleView, Кода что то меняется на сервере, Activity принудительно перезагружается

Comment: Наверное она так делает из-за падения. Посмотрите в логах - наверное у вас там `NPE` или `IndexOfBounds` где-то

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в логах обнаружил что он выдает ошибку, обновлю вопрос.

Comment: Укажите в вопросе строку возникновения ошибки и приведите этот код - в нём у вас и ошибка.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил вопрос

Comment: Видимо у вас `codes.get(i).key` `null` выясните почему - и проблема решится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обнаружены многочисленные ошибки в коде , из за этого и был перезапуск при изменение данный.

Изменил строку :

```
if (codes.get(i).key.equals(codes1.key))
```

На :

```
if (codes.get(i) !=null && codes.get(i).key.equals(codes1.key))
```